# Send Push Notification to users who haven't opened the app yet

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to send push notifications to the users who have installed the app but not opened yet. I am using firebase to send push notifications.

Comment: There's no way.

Comment: no there is no way because for notification you need the device token without device token its not possible

Answer (score 0):

In order for Firebase Cloud Messaging to send messages to an app on a specific device, the app must have [collected a device ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). This requires that the app have been launched at least once, so the app code can get that token and send it to your backend.  If the app was never launched, that means it never had a chance to collect that token, and messaging to it is impossible.

Comment: can I catch any event such as Broadcast receiver or any other installation event to collect the device id?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything. That sounds like a new question to post.