# Question on the behaviour of Android push notification system (Android 10 and above)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play

Is it possible that a downloaded and installed app can still do push notifications even though the **user has never once  launched** the app?

Comment: It's not possible https://stackoverflow.com/q/60523739/8251780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Firebase Cloud Messaging to send messages to an app on a specific device, the app must have collected a device ID token. This requires that the app have been launched at least once, so the app code can get that token and send it to your backend. If the app was never launched, that means it never had a chance to collect that token, and messaging to it is not possible.

Comment: What about those app not using Firebase? Does installation alone create hooks that can  deliver to device ID?